# 100% width Background Image

Tags: html, css, image, tumblr

I'm trying to do a background image of 100% and have an image as the background. When I upload the image it goes to 100% but it cuts off have the picture. It makes the image wider than my screen. How do I fix it where the picture width is 100% but the image width fits the screen without getting cut off. Here is my tumblr to let you see what I mean (http://ophelialogy.tumblr.com/) and here is the full image to show you the full image and give you an idea for where it's cutting off (http://imageshack.us/a/img7/7103/khb3.png).

Here is my code: 
CSS PART

```
    /* --- HEADER --- */
#header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    {block:IfAdjustableHeader}height:{text:Header Height};{/block:IfAdjustableHeader}
    {block:IfNotAdjustableHeader}height:100%;{/block:IfNotAdjustableHeader}
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background-image: url('{image:header}');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


/* --- PAGE CONTENT --- */
#page {
    {block:IfAdjustableHeader}top:{text:Header Height};{/block:IfAdjustableHeader}
    {block:IfNotAdjustableHeader}top:100%;{/block:IfNotAdjustableHeader}
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: {color:Background};
    z-index: 99;
}

.container {
    margin: 50px auto 0px;
    {block:If400Posts}width: 800px;{/block:If400Posts}
    {block:If500Posts}width: 900px;{/block:If500Posts}
}




/* --- POSTS --- */
.postcol {
    width: 540px;
    margin-left: 240px;
}

.posts {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
} 

.posts img, .posts li, .posts blockquote {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

HTML Part

```
<body>

<div id="header">
<div class="description">{Description}</div>
</div>


<div id="page">
<div class="container">





<div class="postcol">


{block:Posts}
<div class="posts">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I was getting some cool results using the `fluidratio` styling found [here](http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios) on your `description` div, with the height reset to 400px and the url to your image, of course. (I removed the height and background styling from `#header` to do this)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
background-image: url(../images/myimage.jpg);
background-size: cover;
```

Do you want the background image in the header or on the main page?

It is currently in the header.

Set the background image on the html tag if you want it to cover the whole page.

Nasser's link to do that is a good one (I would leave out the browser specific hacks though).

EDIT

AHH You're talking about width.

I think it might be something to do with the irritating slider tumblr have coming in from the right - it is about that much too stretched.

I suggest trying these styles on jsfiddler - or another separate site - you'll probably find it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

this excellent blog post explains exactly what you need, without any third party tools:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image

also, there are some jQuery plugins for that, including:

- https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas
- https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

## SO...

What cover does (in my mind) is take the background image and do it's best to use the most of it that it can depending on the height or width of the box it is in. There are 2 ways to deal with this. One way is to make the box the perfect ratio for the image. The other is to actually use an img that will stretch the box to it's exact size. Here is how to do each. The plus of the background-image version, is that you can easily only serve a small version to small screens with an @media rule.

### HTML

```
<header class="container global-header"></header>

<header class="container global-header2">
    <img alt="banner-thing" src="http://placekitten.com/400/100" />
</header>
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.global-header {
    width: 100%;

    /* this is hacky - but it is your answer */
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 25%;

    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/400/100");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    /* you should have this too */
    background-position: center center;
}

.global-header2 {
    width: 100%;
    /* height will be determined by image size */
}

.global-header2 img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/hnvEv/)